# 10 times as many page faults when using a single core vs 2+ cores

Tags: python, linux, numpy, multiprocessing, page-fault

I am observing an odd behavior in a parallel code that I am developing with Python 3.6/Numpy under Linux: running it on 2 cores is about 3 times faster than running it on a single core. I am not sure I understand the exact issue but I have managed to find some clues:

1. Using perf I found out that I get many more page faults with one core rather than 2 (partial runs are they are long running jobs):

1 core

```
   57414.449252      task-clock:u (msec)       #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
              0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec                  
              0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec                  
     22,583,368      page-faults:u             #    0.393 M/sec                  
115,569,738,160      cycles:u                  #    2.013 GHz                    
 22,655,695,268      stalled-cycles-frontend:u #   19.60% frontend cycles idle   
 32,251,136,400      stalled-cycles-backend:u  #   27.91% backend cycles idle    
189,041,318,733      instructions:u            #    1.64  insn per cycle         
                                               #    0.17  stalled cycles per insn
 38,298,469,811      branches:u                #  667.053 M/sec                  
    654,389,291      branch-misses:u           #    1.71% of all branches        
 83,343,166,583      L1-dcache-loads:u         # 1451.606 M/sec                  
    318,284,548      L1-dcache-load-misses:u   #    0.38% of all L1-dcache hits  
 25,589,478,853      L1-icache-loads:u         #  445.698 M/sec                  
  2,560,674,130      L1-icache-load-misses:u   #   10.01% of all L1-icache hits  
 83,377,552,384      dTLB-loads:u              # 1452.205 M/sec                  
    216,145,062      dTLB-load-misses:u        #    0.26% of all dTLB cache hits 
 25,626,979,550      iTLB-loads:u              #  446.351 M/sec                  
     55,847,490      iTLB-load-misses:u        #    0.22% of all iTLB cache hits 
        222,176      L1-dcache-prefetches:u    #    0.004 M/sec                  
        220,870      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u #    0.004 M/sec
```

2 cores

```
  111569.269846      task-clock:u (msec)       #    1.837 CPUs utilized         
              0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec                 
              0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec                 
      4,415,116      page-faults:u             #    0.040 M/sec                 
330,750,606,867      cycles:u                  #    2.965 GHz                   
 69,517,418,862      stalled-cycles-frontend:u #   21.02% frontend cycles idle  
104,365,888,484      stalled-cycles-backend:u  #   31.55% backend cycles idle   
609,338,385,634      instructions:u            #    1.84  insn per cycle        
                                               #    0.17  stalled cycles per ins
125,341,622,204      branches:u                # 1123.442 M/sec                 
  1,860,702,685      branch-misses:u           #    1.48% of all branches       
261,941,396,767      L1-dcache-loads:u         # 2347.792 M/sec                 
    935,372,306      L1-dcache-load-misses:u   #    0.36% of all L1-dcache hits 
 79,306,212,694      L1-icache-loads:u         #  710.825 M/sec                 
  7,337,551,130      L1-icache-load-misses:u   #    9.25% of all L1-icache hits 
261,578,594,355      dTLB-loads:u              # 2344.540 M/sec                 
    425,510,820      dTLB-load-misses:u        #    0.16% of all dTLB cache hits
 79,008,997,415      iTLB-loads:u              #  708.161 M/sec                 
    102,332,385      iTLB-load-misses:u        #    0.13% of all iTLB cache hits
        944,223      L1-dcache-prefetches:u    #    0.008 M/sec                 
        945,497      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u #    0.008 M/sec
```

2. Running perf top indicates that ~35% of the time is spent in the kernel with these functions being the top contributors:

   ```
   clear_page_rep
   page_fault
   check_preemption_disabled
   get_page_from_freelist
   __handle_mm_fault
   free_pcppages_bulk
   __pagevec_lru_add_fn
   sync_regs release_pages
   handle_mm_fault
   preempt_count_add
   ```

   .
3. I seems that at least part of the issue is created when copying a Numpy array of roughly ~15×3500 floats but not every single time. The code essentially computes models on a Cartesian grid of physical parameters and makes frequent copies of an object that contains a few Numpy arrays. Now, for some copies (but not all) of that object the copy of this one ~15×3500 Numpy array takes ~15 times longer, I assume due to the page fault. The code frequently creates/deletes these objects but the overall memory associated to each process varies slowly (the results are written into a shared RawArray) so I would believe that memory should normally be reallocated (the creation of a new objects happens soon after the destruction of the previous one). This happens only whenever a single core is used, not when using more cores.
4. I tried to start two independent runs using 1 core each at the same time and they both have a high number of page faults. So it does not seem related to running several processes at the same time.
5. When running on a single core I tried both with multiprocessing (spawn and fork) and without, the result is the same, with a high number of page faults. So it does not seem to be related
6. This occurs both with the Archlinux python packages and with the Anaconda packages.
7. This occurs both on an AMD EPYC 7351 with 512 GB or RAM and on an Intel Core i7 6700K with 64 GB of RAM (both running Archlinux). The code uses ~10 GB of RAM, mostly in the form of RawArrays to store the result. The RAM used in individual objects should be ~500 kB per object and there should not be more than 7-8 of them in RAM at any given moment.

I am a bit lost as to why I am getting so many page faults when running on a single core but not when running on 2+ cores. Any idea what may be happening and possible ways to fix it? I am trying to measure how the code scales up with the number of cores so I would like a reliable data point when running on a single core. As is using 2 cores is 3 times faster than running on a single core.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem!  Any chance that you can create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  That would make it much easier for someone to help you.  Without code, the best anyone can do is guess (but you might get some very informed guesses).

Comment: I have tried but so far I have not been able to exhibit the issue with a minimal example, unfortunately.